# error: expected expression before ‘st’

Tags: c, struct

I was trying out this simple structure program in C but on compiling, I was getting the following error at 3 places (line 17,20 and 22). I went through the code but could not find the mistake. Where am I going wrong?

Note: I am getting the same errors if I put the structure declaration and the typedef statement inside the main() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct my_struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

typedef struct my_struct st;

void main()
{
    printf("Enterting values into the structure.\n");

    printf("Enter value of a:\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&st.a); 

    printf("Enter value of b:\n");
    scanf("%d",&st.b);

    printf("Values of a is: %d.\nValue of b is: %d.\n",st.a,st.b);
}
```

Comment: the return type from the main() function is ALWAYS 'int'.   Your compiler should have told you that.  Always fix the problems that your compiler tells you about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`st` is type of object, like `int`, `char` etc. it is not the name of variable.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct my_struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

typedef struct my_struct st;

int main()
{
    st str;

    printf("Enterting values into the structure.\n");

    printf("Enter value of a:\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&str.a); 

    printf("Enter value of b:\n");
    scanf("%d",&str.b);

    printf("Values of a is: %d.\nValue of b is: %d.\n",str.a,str.b);
}
```

Comment: This answer has a `void main()` which is not a valid statement as main always returns int

Comment: @user3629249 thank you for your correction ;) was explaining to somebody why not `void main()` and I ended up putting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`st` is an object type . Inside `main` declare a struct variable -

```
 st st1;
```

And then use it to access members.

`void main()` **->** `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc,char ** argv)`

Answer (score 1):

You defined a struct and a typedef.

but you never declared an instance of the struct.

As a suggestion, just remove the word 'typedef',

then fix the main() function declaration